# Using PowerMockRunner with Junit Test Suite

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock, powermockito

I'm trying to create a `Junit` test suite along with using `PowerMockRunner` but it does not work.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(MainTest.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({ MainTest.Class1Test.class })
@PrepareForTest({
    StaticFieldsProvider.class
})
public class MainTest extends Suite {

public MainTest(Class<?> klass, RunnerBuilder builder)
        throws InitializationError {
    super(klass, builder);
}

public static class TestBase {
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(StaticFieldsProvider.class);
    }
}

public static class Class1Test extends TestBase {
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        super.setUp();
    }

    @Test
    public void test(){
        assertTrue(true);
    }
 }
}
```

When I try to run, it fails with error -

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Test class can only have one constructor
>       at org.junit.runners.model.TestClass.(TestClass.java:40)

Any suggestions on how to use `PowerMockRunner` in above case?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want a constructor?

Comment: Without that constructor, it doesn't really compile as there is no default constructor in `Suite` class.

Comment: I would love a solution to this. My runner works if `@RunWith(Suite.class)`, but then I can't also `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)`...

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, so we may get no resolution on whether or not this solution works for the OP; but this might work (I can't verify without having access to `StaticFieldsProvider`, but it works if I swap that out with one of my own classes). I would love for someone to edit and add more explanation as to why this works:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
// * Delegate to Suite.class instead of MainTest.class *
@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({ MainTest.Class1Test.class })
@PrepareForTest({
        StaticFieldsProvider.class
})
// * Don't extend Suite *
public class MainTest {

// * Remove constructor *

    public static class TestBase {
        @Before
        public void setUp() {
            MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
            PowerMockito.mockStatic(StaticFieldsProvider.class);
        }
    }

    public static class Class1Test extends TestBase {
        @Before
        public void setUp() {
            super.setUp();
        }

        @Test
        public void test(){
            assertTrue(true);
        }
    }
}
```

In case it helps someone else, I had a slightly different scenario in that only a couple of the classes in my suite need `PowerMockRunner` (and don't mock out the same thing, so the mock needs to happen in each individual test class instead of in the runner). It appears that as long as I `@PrepareForTest` in my runner (as above) the classes I will need in some of the test classes, I can still create the mocks in the `@Before` (or wherever) of the applicable test class. Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

You must not extend `Suite`, because this is a part of JUnit 3 and you are using JUnit 4. (Remove the `extends` and the constructor.) See the [JUnit Wiki](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Aggregating-tests-in-suites) for more datails about Suites in JUnit 4.

Comment: I'm willing to change my vote, but this is currently unhelpful. Removing the `extends` and constructor does not make what the OP wants to do work. I'm trying to do the same thing and would love to know how to actually do it.